firebase authentication stops working after navigating to a different page,
This one is really frustrating.
I have implement firebase authentication in my Blazor Web App (.Net 8) specifying the popup sign-in flow .
Everything works fine as long I stay on the very same page from where I have initially logged in. So, Sign-in Sign-out works perfect multiple times.
Problem starts, when I navigate to a different page. (Even after coming back to the original page). Then, when trying to sign in (with a provider other than email/password) after credentials validation, the authentication popup iframe gets stuck for a while after which it disappears, but firebase authentication has not succeeded. So user is undefined.
A strange thing that I have noticed though, is that as long I have not navigated away from the original page, I can see on the network traffic of my site the authorisation traffic such as https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp? and https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup.
But after navigation, the network tab doesn't show any more any of those requests. It seems that those request are coming from the firebase server direct?
Any clue of where to take it from here, please?
